# How to get all person instances with its height from DBpedia?

Tags: api, mediawiki, dbpedia, wikidata

I'm working on a project that displays celebs height
and Wikidata does not always provide the information needed.
So I considered DBpedia as another option and spent days trying to find out how to deal with it

- how can I fetch every instance of Person class with its Height in
  DBpedia, is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SPARQL to export the data from DBPedia (http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql/).

```
select * where {
    ?person dbo:Person\/height ?height.
}
LIMIT 10000 OFFSET 10000
```

The public endpoint limits the size of result sets, currently to 10000 rows, so you'll have to step through the data with an increasing OFFSET, or you find a better endpoint for your need.

Comment: THANKS A LOT, do you know what are the differences between the dbo:hieght and dbo:person\height ?

Comment: dbo:height isn't specific to persons, so there is for example a car (http://dbpedia.org/page/BMW_501) with a dbo:height.